# Differentiate to get error on weighted mean (summation fraction)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, summation, average, means

I need help differentiating a fraction containing two summations.

Given the weighted mean

$
\bar{x} = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\rm N} x_{i}/\sigma_{i}^{2}}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\rm N} 1/\sigma_{i}^{2}}$

where $x_{i}$ and $\sigma_{i}$ are uncorrelated.
The *error propagation formula*

$\sigma_{f}^2 = \sigma_{f}^2 \left(\frac{\delta f }{\delta x}\right)^2 +  \sigma_{f}^2 \left(\frac{\delta f }{\delta y}\right)^2 + ...$

yields the error on $\bar{x}$ as:
$\sigma_{\bar{x}}^2 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\rm N} \left(\frac{\delta \bar{x} }{\delta x_{i}}\right)^2  \sigma_{i}^2$

The literature* solves the derivative as:

$\frac{\delta \bar{x} }{\delta x_{i}} = \frac{\delta }{\delta x_{i}} \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\rm N} x_{i}/\sigma_{i}^2}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\rm N} 1/\sigma_{i}^2}
 = \frac{1/\sigma_{i}^2}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\rm N} 1/\sigma_{i}^2}$

I cannot figure out how this result is achieved. By my working, if $\sigma_{i}$ can be treated as a constant, then $\frac{\delta \bar{x} }{\delta x_{i}}=1$.

Am I missing something? I have tried the Quotient rule but I don't see how it applies in this case.

Eqn. 4.19, Bevington, *Data Reduction and Error Analysis for the Physical Sciences*
http://astro.cornell.edu/academics/courses/astro3310/Books/Bevington_opt.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to apply the quotient rule, since the function is linear in each $x_i, 1\leq i\leq N$. Let's denote the constant
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}=C
\end{align*}

The function can then be written for $1\leq i\leq N$
\begin{align*}
\overline{x}&=\frac{1}{C}\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{x_j}{\sigma_j^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{C\sigma_i^2}x_i+\frac{1}{C}\sum_{{j=1}\atop{j\ne i}}^N\frac{x_j}{\sigma_j^2}
\end{align*}
which is of the form 
\begin{align*}
\overline{x}(x_i)=a x_i + b\qquad\qquad a,b \quad\text{const.}
\end{align*}

> The derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\overline{x}$ is therefore
>
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\overline{x}&=\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}\left(
> \frac{1}{C\sigma_i^2}x_i+\frac{1}{C}\sum_{{j=1}\atop{j\ne i}}^N\frac{x_j}{\sigma_j^2}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{C\sigma_i^2}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad 1\leq i\leq N
> \end{align*}

**Note:** We have to use a different index variable $j$ for summation to avoid conflicts with the variable $x_i$.

---

> **Add-on: [2017-01-22]** Some remarks to the index notation with respect to OPs comments.
>
> It seems that Eqn 4.18 in the referred book causes some troubles due to the index notation.
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{\sum\left(x_i/\sigma_i^2\right)}{\sum\left(1/\sigma_i^2\right)}
> =\frac{1/\sigma_i^2}{\sum\left(1/\sigma_i^2\right)}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

At first we take a look at the left hand side of (1). The expression can be equivalently written as
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{\sum\left(x_i/\sigma_i^2\right)}{\sum\left(1/\sigma_i^2\right)}
=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{\sum\left(x_j/\sigma_j^2\right)}{\sum\left(1/\sigma_k^2\right)}
=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N}\left(x_j/\sigma_j^2\right)}{\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left(1/\sigma_k^2\right)}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> When looking at $x_i$ in 
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum\left(x_i/\sigma_i^2\right)\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>   the index $i$ is a so-called *[bound variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables)*. This means
>
> - the scope of $i$ in (3)  belongs to the $\Sigma$ symbol and is limited by the parenthesis
>
> $$\sum\color{blue}{\left(\right.}x_i/\sigma_i^2\color{blue}{\left.\right)}$$
>
> - any usage of $i$ somewhere else means another, different symbol
> - the symbol $i$ in the derivative operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ has nothing to do with the symbol $i$ in (3)
> - the symbol $i$ in the sum $\sum\left(1/\sigma_i^2\right)$ has nothing to do with $i$ in (3).
>
> **Hint:** Since the indices $i$ in the two sums and in the derivative operator have nothing in common, it is usually more convenient to use distinct variable names, e.g. $i,j,k$ as we can see in (2).

The expression $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ stands for the derivative of any $x_i$ *arbitrarily, fixed* chosen from $1\leq i \leq N$.

Albeit the notation the authors use is mathematically correct, it should be avoided as overloading of the same symbol makes the text harder to read for the less experienced.

Comment: Thanks very much. Would you mind clarifying the steps taken to get:

$\dfrac{1}{C} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{N}\frac{x_{j}}{\sigma_{j}^2} = \frac{1}{C\sigma_{i}^2}x_{i} + \dfrac{1}{C} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{N}\frac{x_{j}}{\sigma_{j}^2}$

Comment: @smashbro: You're welcome! The sum is split into two parts. The first part consists of the term with index $i$ only, the second part is the sum of all other terms with index $j, j\ne i$. Note that at the bottom of the summation sign $i$ is explicitly excluded.

Comment: Why is there only one term with the index $i$ rather than $n$ terms?

Comment: @smashbro: The partial derivative is done with respect to $x_i$. The summation index $j$ is bounded to the summation symbol $\Sigma$ and independent from the index $i$. In fact it is necessary to denote the summation index with another symbol than $i$. We have to avoid using the same symbol for different usage.

Comment: @smashbro: I've added some information which might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Note that:
$\frac{\delta }{\delta x_{i}} \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\rm N} x_{i}/\sigma_{i}^2}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\rm N} 1/\sigma_{i}^2}
= \frac{1}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\rm N} 1/\sigma_{i}^2}\frac{\delta }{\delta x_{i}} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\rm N} x_{i}/\sigma_{i}^2
~~~\mathbf{\neq}~~~
\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\rm N} 1/\sigma_{i}^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\rm N}\frac{\delta }{\delta x_{i}}(x_i/\sigma_i^2)
$

It's very, very easy to mistake the inequality for an equality because *the same* letter $i$ in the leftmost and central terms is used to denote *three different* index variables, inside and outside of the two summations: there's a very high risk of confusing two different things both called $i$ when the $\frac{\delta }{\delta x_{i}}$ operator is "brought inside" the summation in the rightmost term. Using for the three different indices  three different names $h,i,j$ (a highly recommended "safety practice") yields a slightly uglier but far less misleading:

$\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\rm N} 1/\sigma_{i}^2}\frac{\delta }{\delta x_{i}} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\rm N} x_{i}/\sigma_{i}^2
=
\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{h=1}^{\rm N} 1/\sigma_{h}^2}\frac{\delta }{\delta x_{i}} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\rm N} x_{j}/\sigma_{j}^2
=
\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{h=1}^{\rm N} 1/\sigma_{h}^2} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\rm N} \frac{\delta }{\delta x_{i}} (x_{j}/\sigma_{j}^2)
=
\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{h=1}^{\rm N} 1/\sigma_{h}^2} (1/\sigma_i^2)$

since $\frac{\delta }{\delta x_{i}} (x_{j}/\sigma_{j}^2)=0$ if $i\neq j$.